# Triple equals in return php

Tags: php

I saw the line below in a class method :

```
return $return === 1;
```

What's the meaning of this ? As "===" is a comparaison operator, what would be the expected behavior of using this operator directly in a return ? Return only if 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: It will always return, but return true if `$return` is (in both value and type) = 1, otherwise it will return false.

Comment: Having conditionals on a `return` is fine... shaves making a toss-away variable just to return in the next line. Its more concise, cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. It's all clear now